# Adding dagger and affiliation

Tags: author, affiliation

I need to add a dagger to the main author in the neptune latex tool for Elsevier, and I dont manage to do it correctly. Here is the code

```
\documentclass[fleqn,s1,numnames,tex]{neptune}

\author[a]{My name, surname}

\cormark[1]
\cortext[1]{\CORAT
 \TFadd[a].
}

\email[myemail@aaa.ni]

\affiliation[a]{o={My department}, a={Address}, c={City}, cp={}, p={9037}, cy={Country}}
```

I have tried to add \dagger witithin [ ], i.e. [a,\dagger], and then add \affiliation[\dagger]{ }, but that doesnt work.

Comment: `\cormark` is not a standard command. Please add the details about the document class.

Comment: Maybe it's [els-cas](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/els-cas-templates/)?

Comment: I updated the class document. I have also asked for help to Elsevier, but I guess it will take some time.